# Group by Latest entry and filter out with additional criterias

Tags: php, mysql, sql

<sub>Table:</sub>

```
id    sender    receiver        message
 1      14        16            1st message from 14 to 16
 2      16        14            1st message from 16 to 14
 3      16        14            2nd message from 16 to 14
 4      14        16            2nd message from 14 to 16
 5      15        14            1st message from 15 to 14
 6      15        14            2nd message from 15 to 14
 7      14        16            3rd message from 14 to 16
 8      14        16            4th message from 14 to 16
 9      14        15            1st message from 14 to 15
10      14        15            2nd message from 14 to 15
```

Now, what I am trying to do here to is to group the messages for one user (as a receiver), but the problem is that **I want the latest entry regardless of who sent the message**.

<sub>Attempt 1:</sub>

```
SELECT c2. *
FROM (

SELECT max( id ) `id`
FROM tbl_msg
GROUP BY `sender`
)c1
INNER JOIN tbl_msg c2 ON c1.id = c2.id
WHERE `receiver` =14
GROUP BY `sender`
```

<sub>Result:</sub>

```
id    sender    receiver        message
 6      15        14            2nd message from 15 to 14
 3      16        14            2nd message from 16 to 14
```

Here the result is that each last message is **sent to user 14**. It obviously won't include the message sent **by** user 14.

Again, I can't use an addtional `GROUP BY` on `receiver`, because then it would only include the last entry **sent by** user 14.

<sub>Expected output:</sub>

```
id    sender    receiver        message
10      14        15            2nd message from 14 to 15
 8      14        16            4th message from 14 to 16
```

Now in the above, `sender` in both the entries are 14, but it can be any user.

*In simple words:*,

> I want to retrieve the last message in a conversation between A and B,
>   regardless of who said it.

Is using `GROUP BY` here a wrong approach?

N.B. The questions below are somewhat similiar to this question **with the exception** that they deal with only one criteria. But here, I have two (i.e. the user can be either a sender or a receiver). This is the part where I am stuck at.

[Retrieving the last record in each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group)

[MySQL - Control which row is returned by a group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537223/mysql-control-which-row-is-returned-by-a-group-by)

[Returning the 'last' row of each 'group by' in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192673/returning-the-last-row-of-each-group-by-in-mysql)

[1st Row in Group By vs. Last Row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7716181/1st-row-in-group-by-vs-last-row)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
SELECT  *
FROM    TableName
WHERE   (LEAST(sender, receiver),GREATEST(sender, receiver), id) 
        IN (
                SELECT  LEAST(sender, receiver) AS x,
                        GREATEST(sender, receiver) AS y,
                        MAX(id) AS max_ID
                FROM    TableName
                GROUP   BY x, y
            )
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1ad63/4)

OUTPUT

```
╔════╦════════╦══════════╦═══════════════════════════╗
║ ID ║ SENDER ║ RECEIVER ║          MESSAGE          ║
╠════╬════════╬══════════╬═══════════════════════════╣
║  8 ║     14 ║       16 ║ 4th message from 14 to 16 ║
║ 10 ║     14 ║       15 ║ 2nd message from 14 to 15 ║
╚════╩════════╩══════════╩═══════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: exactly what i wanted. a little bit puzzled about the sql though. can you tell me what part does comparing the ids of `sender` and `receiver` is playing here?

Comment: it's on the subquery, see here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1ad63/6 the purpose of the outer query is to be able to get all remaining columns in the table.

Comment: one problem i am seeing here (just now discovered) is, it applies for datas for the least id (14 here). let's say i want to retreive the last messages of user15 against 14 and 16. or last message with respect to user 16 against 14 and 15. how should it be improvised?

Comment: actually it's not about the `LEAST()`. It's all because of the `ID`. Why don;t you have any dates between the conversation. using `ID`, *I guess it is AUTO_INCREMENTed*, is not reliable at all.

Comment: yes. in one of the above links in the question, one has mentioned it. let's say if i use date field, then what should be the column type for this purpose two fields for `date` and `time`, `datetime` or `timestamp`? can you add the releveant query on the basis of that (date and time field) for above?

Comment: i prefer `datetime` then in the query replace `ID` to your `datetime` column.